error when deploying nodejs project in render.com
As captioned, I got following errors when deploying the project in render.com:
==> Cloning from https://github.com/Marcussyl/puppeteer-server
==> Checking out commit e08cf9810e5e1191e068819b199c2873ba68f519 in branch main
==> Using Node version 20.15.1 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running build command 'npx webpack'...
CLI for webpack must be installed.
  webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D webpack-cli".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): ==> Build failed 
==> Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys

I have setup the build cmd in package.json, how should i solve this error?
